# Flask - Passing parameters to a JQuery $.getJSON callback

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to pass a string to the python callback function from my JQuery $.getJSON. However, the value never reaches the callback. Documentation is not clear to me on this matter .. so I have gleamed what I thought was a solution from other StackOverflow questions.

The variable that is not getting passed back is que_token (*see code below*). This  process is otherwise running successfully via its interval loop with variables from the python method making its way to JQuery ..

```
<script type=text/javascript>
var interval = setInterval(
  function()
  {
    $.getJSON('/_update_alert',  { que_token: "Passing as None" }, function(data) {
      $("#alert-msg").text(data.result.alert_msg);
      $("#alert-type").attr("class", data.result.alert_type)
        var stopSession = data.result.End
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = document.getElementById("log").innerHTML +
            data.result.message_log + "\n"
        if (data.result.End == "True") {
            clearInterval(interval);
    }

    });
    return false;
  },
  2000);
</script>

@app.route('/_update_alert/<que_token>')
@login_required
def update_alert(que_token=None):
    if que_token is None:
        # que_token should not be None - ERROR
        que_token = session['que_token']
    alert_data = {}
    .....
    return jsonify(result=alert_data)
```

The python trace shows that the value que_token is making its way back .. but my python function 'update_alert' is not picking it up.

```
127.0.0.1 -[01/Nov/2016 14:58:02] "GET /_update_alert?que_token=Passing+as+None HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Using flask `request.args.get('que_token', '')` in my python function update_alert() solves this question. But this is not as direct as picking off que_token from the functions update_alert passed argument.

So one solution to my question is:

```
@app.route('/_update_alert')
@login_required
def update_alert():
    que_token = request.args.get('que_token', '')
    .....
    alert_data = {}
    .....
    return jsonify(result=alert_data)
```

I will use this as my answer unless someone comes forward and explains why I cannot use the original method (*via a Get request flask parameter*).

Comment: upvoted! can you not get the data in your case using request.get_json()